# Aggregation and Total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT  Region ,
        flag ,
        Name,
        COUNT(ID) AS 'CountWithFlag'
FROM    Table
GROUP BY flag
```

this query gives me the following results. I am grouping by flag and I am able to get the counts for English/non-English based on flag. I also want to display Total Counts of English and non-English adjacent to counts

OUTPUT:

```
Region Flag  Name     CountWithFlag
a      0     English        100
b      1     Non-English    200 
c      0     English        100
d      1     Non-English    200
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Region Flag  Name     CountWithFlag  Total
a      0     English        100       200
b      1     Non-English    200       400
c      0     English        100       200
d      1     Non-English    200       400
```

How can I do that? I want to apply group by for specific counts with flag. But I also want to get total counts in same query!

Any inputs on how I can do that?

Comment: I don't understand what aggregation you want for your `Total` column, but just do separate aggregations of the same dataset and join the resulting subqueries.

Comment: Total column with aggregation of Name. By English and Non-English.

Comment: I did SUM(COUNT(ID)) OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ) AS total. That solved the purpose. But I am trying to dig in if there's any other way of doing it?

Comment: Any inputs on how I can separately aggregate and join?

Comment: You can use a computed column. Create a function that calculate the sum based on your `Name` value and use it as value for your `Total` column. Check here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be something like this:

```
;
WITH    agg1
            AS (
                SELECT  region,
                        flag,
                        name,
                        COUNT(id) AS 'CountWithFlag'
                FROM    [dbo].[t2]
                GROUP BY region,
                        flag,
                        name
                ),
        agg2
            AS (
                SELECT  [name],
                        COUNT(id) AS CountByName
                FROM    [dbo].[t2]
                GROUP BY [name]
                )
    SELECT  [agg1].[region],
            [agg1].[flag],
            [agg1].[name],
            [agg1].[CountWithFlag],
            [agg2].[CountByName]
    FROM    [agg1]
            INNER JOIN [agg2]
                ON [agg2].[name] = [agg1].[name]
```

Comment: SELECT  region,
                        flag,
                        name,
                        COUNT(id) AS 'CountWithFlag',SUM(COUNT(ID)) OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ) AS total,
                FROM    [dbo].[t2]
                GROUP BY region,
                        flag,
                        name                                      How about this query? This gives me the same result too. Although I am not very sure I should use SUm PARTITION By?? Any Ideas?

Comment: I would still in most cases prefer the OVER clause, but you should always check the execution plans to make sure what's better

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  ;
    WITH    cte
              AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                            Region ,
                            flag ,
                            Name ,
                            COUNT(ID) OVER ( PARTITION BY flag, Region, Name ) AS [CountWithFlag]
                   FROM     [Table]
                 )
        SELECT  Region ,
                flag ,
                Name ,
                SUM([CountWithFlag]) OVER ( PARTITION BY Name ) AS Total
        FROM    cte
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using window functions, you can do that:

```
SELECT 
  Region,
  flag,
  Name,
  COUNT(ID) AS CountWithFlag,
  (select count(ID) from Table as tbl1 where tbl1.Name=tbl.Name) AS Total
from Table as tbl
group by Region, flag, Name
```

But my opinion is that window aggregation should work much faster.

If you want use window aggregation then do this:

```
select 
  Region,
  flag,
  Name,
  CountWithFlag,
  sum(CountWithFlag) over(partition by Name) as Total
from (
  SELECT 
    Region,
    flag,
    Name,
    COUNT(ID) AS CountWithFlag
  from Table as tbl
  group by Region, flag, Name
) as tbl
```